# DeCAL and Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, decal

Have someone tried out [DeCAL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/decal/) in Delphi 2009?

I'm thinking about upgrading from 2007, but my code is quite dependent on DeCAL...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a DeCAL version that works with Delphi 2009.
https://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/26159

There is also a rewrite of DeCAL using generics but that would require you to rewrite your code. https://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/26124

Answer (score 1):

Fun to see that there is still life in DECAL!

I did a lot of prototyping with it in the past, though it turned out to be too slow for the definitive implementation